# PHP creating an input class title= for the same named field

Tags: php, arrays, joomla

I'm using Joomla to create websites, but am learning php and css as I go along.
I've learned more in CSS, and I am still struggling with PHP. 
Within Joomla (a CMS), I have added a component called foxcontact which is a contact form. I'm using this for a "Request a Quote" form. Within the contact form are many PHP files, but I have located what I need to change. (This is not my coding.)

```
[....]  
$external_label .
    '<input ' .
        'class="' . $this->TextStyleByValidation($field) . '" ' .
     'type="text" ' .
     'value="' . $value . '" ' .
     'title="' . $field['Name'] . '" ' .
     'style="' .
        'width:' . $field['Width'] . $field['Unit'] . ' !important;' .
        '" ' .
     'name="' . $field['PostName'] . '" ' .
        $js .
     '/>' .
[....]
```

There are 4 fields called quantity. I need the title to state Quantity1, Quantity2, etc., for the 4 different quantity fields. 
Is there a way to incorporate an if statement like:

```
[....]  
if ($field['Name'] == "Quantity")   
    $result .= $external_label .
    '<input ' .
        'class="' . $this->TextStyleByValidation($field) . '" ' .
     'type="text" ' .
     'value="' . $value . '" ' .
     **'title=""' .**
     'style="' ;
else
     $result .= $external_label .
     '<input ' .
        'class="' . $this->TextStyleByValidation($field) . '" ' .
     'type="text" ' .
     'value="' . $value . '" ' .
     'title="' . $field['Name'] . '" ' .
     'style="' ;    
[.....]
```

but changing the title= to the relevant quantity1, quantity2 etc.

I have been looking at an array, but cannot get it to work.

Comment: As stated, it isn't my work. I am only editing it. The developer has told me it is awful modifications of what I'm trying to do, but I need it for my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a counter someplace above in the script, like `$i=1` and increment it for each Quantity field. And this is how you should call it:

```
[.....]
'title="' . $field['Name'] . $i . '" ' .
[.....]
```

<strike>Let me know if this wasn't clear enough and you need the whole part written in code.</strike>

Edit, the whole thing:

> lines 21 and 184: <strike>`$i = 1;`</strike>

remove this since we don't need it anymore, we'll put it in as the function parameter:

> line182: private function BuildTextField($key, &$field, **$i=1**)

notice the `$i=1` added as a last parameter with a predefined value.

The rest remains the same (don't forget the curly brackets and the increment line):

```
if ($field['Name'] == "Quantity"){   
    $result .= $external_label .
    '<input ' .
    'class="' . $this->TextStyleByValidation($field) . '" ' .
    'type="text" ' .
    'value="' . $value . '" ' .
    'title="' . $field['Name'] . $i . '" ' .
    'style="' ;
    ++$i;
}
else
[.....]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, all the quantity fields are the same, with the same name of "Quantity". Would this still work? Also, you say i would need to place the $i=1 in the script, is this above the code, and would it be $i="1","2", etc? thanks, Matt

Comment: Yes, it would work like that. Define $i above the code, and add this line just above the `else` line: `++$i;`. See my edit.

Comment: unfortunatly it now fails to load the page (which is normal if the php file is failing, I have found through my edits).

Comment: or i can get it to load up, but it comes up with " Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\wamp\www\joomla1.6-72\components\com_foxcontact\helpers\fieldsbuilder.php on line 215 "

Comment: Check where you defined `$i`, that's the error. It has to be initialized before you enter the if conditions and loops. Try putting it at the very top of the file.

Comment: I placed it the very first line under my opening <?php and comments. i've re-added it, and the page loads fine. then adding the if statement (well even jsut the $i and ++$i) the page fails to laod. however, after changing the ; after style to a . so that the ++$i is the last of the file, it loads fine, but with undefined errors on page 215 "'title="' . $field['Name'] . $i . '" ' ." and 217 "++$i; " - The contact form loads (with the errors at top of the page) but loses some styling further down the php and doesnt change the title! Thanks, Matt

Comment: Oh man, see my latest edit... it's the if clause, needs curly brackets now since there's more than one command in it, sorry.

Comment: One question though: why didn't you just make those 4 components in the Joomla module?

Comment: Just waiting for my akeeba to restore (from work to home), and will try to clunky brackets when its loaded! Thanks for your help! but, what do you mean just make those 4 components in Joomla module. It is a full contact form that gets emailed to many people within the office, with an email to the customer too...

Comment: Hi Shomz, sorry but this has again loaded the page below the undefined errors, and cancels the styling which is below the if statement shown here. thanks for all your help.

Comment: I meant there has to be a way to choose which fields you want in the form, so instead Quantity, you put Quantity1 and add the other three.

Comment: thats possible yes, but i would prefer for it to just state quantity. as it would be more professional. Also, in the script, it closes the <div> after each text field, and i have done much editing to keep the div open after each "item", and moving the next "quantity" to the right of it...

Comment: If you want you can either show the whole code here or send it to me, since it's hard for both of us to debug it this way.

Comment: no problem, what is the easiest way to send it to you? also i'm only editing one .php file, there are many in the component, but this is called fieldsbuilder.php - the one that builds the fields. You want only this one? fyi, for more info, here i am speaking to the developer - http://www.fox.ra.it/forum/5-support/2495-add-extra-box-next-to-exsisting-box.html

Comment: Hm, perhaps you could upload the file somewhere and send me the url - I don't know if I could send you a private message here. And only the file you're editing would be enough.

Comment: yep sure, i have uplaoded it to my webspace - http://www.mattman.org/images/files/fieldsbuilder.rar - I had to make it a rar file as the browser was trying to access the php.

Comment: ok, got it... you didn't copy it right - the row above `++$i;` (line 216) you have to close it with `;` rather than leaving concatation with `.`, ok? do it just like I wrote you in my answer. also initialize the $i variable at the beginning of that function, so line 184 = `$i = 1;`

Comment: Hi Shomz, that is brilliant, thank you very much for all your help with this, however, it is giving me the desired effect. That has given them all the title of "Quantity1" where I want it to be "Quantity1, Quantity2" etc. Is it even possible. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad I could help you! The problem now is that you're either 1) re-initializing the `$i` somewhere so it doesn't get a change to increase its value... or 2) incrementation is not working for some reason... I'll have a look again and update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Shomz, I look forward to your reply. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer right after I posted the previous comment... If you still have problems with it, we'll chat.

Comment: Hi Shomz, it is still given me the quantity1 in all the fields. Do you have any more suggestions? I'm starting to think I may need to change the module to state quantity1 quantity 2 and have it look messy. again, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Weird, can you upload the file to your server again so I can take a look?

Comment: yep sure, i have uploaded it again to the same space so the address is the same as the above one - I have also uploaded the whole component there too, which would be http://www.mattman.org/images/files/com_foxcontact.rar if you wanted to check that out, however, I do believe that the only php script I should be changing is the fieldsbuilder.php script... again, thank you very much! I dont know if you are familiar with Joomla, I could send you an akeeba backup with a login for you?

Comment: Ok, if this doesn't work, you'll give me the access. It's definitely just that one file, I'm just not sure how Joomla calls it. I've made a small changes to the class, so try it out now: http://pastebin.com/WR0WvYG3

Comment: Shomz, Thank you very much, this has given me what i want! However, (and this makes me really embarrassed), the email that it has sent me, doesnt have the correct quantities. It all has the same quantity, so i guess it is being pulled from, the label, and not the input class, meaning that I havwe to have the label as Quantity1, Quantity2 etc, which I was trying to avoid! I feel very bad asking you to help me out with this, and it hasnt even given me what I want! I'm very very very greatful, and sorry at the same time!

Comment: Haha, I was afraid of that in the very beginning when I suggested you just make additional fields. I guess we both learned something from this, so don't feel bad. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Shomz last comment got what I wanted, but what I wanted didnt do what I want... 
the whole modified PHP code can be found here... if anyone is interested!
http://pastebin.com/WFK9hfpx

Shomz, again, thank you very very much!

Comment: btw. thanks for the negative rep you gave me - made my time spent for you really worthwhile...

Comment: Sorry i'm new to stack overflow. I didnt really know what i was doing. I have now ticked your answer, is there anything else I can do? obviously im very greatful to you, and want to set it right

Comment: Don't worry, sorry if I was over the board, I was just surprised you didn't respond. Everything's cool.